# Is there a type definition language designed to translate types between languages?

Tags: types, programming-languages

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to define my types once using some kind of language or markup (yaml, json or similar) then use another tool to export/translate the type to a target language - ensuring the types match to the equivalent types in the destination language.

Does such a "type specific" language exist?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possible difficulties of properly translating an Ada type definition into an equivalent C type.

```
type Angle is mod 360;
```

The Ada type defines an unsigned integer with a minimum valid value of 0 and a maximum valid value of 359. The type exhibits wrap-around behavior at the valid value limits. In other words subtracting 1 from 0 results in 359 and adding 1 to 359 results in 0.

C has no equivalent type. An unsigned byte is cannot hold the maximum value. An unsigned word cannot limit the maximum value to 359. While the wrap-around semantics are built into the Ada type definition, the C programmer must manually write specialized arithmetic functions to implement the corresponding wrap around semantics. Much work must be done beyond simply declaring a type in C to produce a truly equivalent type to that defined in the Ada type declaration.